# Retrieving Firebase Child Value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
function sontinue() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var uid = user.uid; 

    var adaRef = firebase.database().ref("User/" + uid);
    if (adaRef.orderByChild("Role").equalTo("admin")) {
        location.href = "DB.html";
    } else {
        location.href = "index.html";
    }

}
```

I would like to link my **"admin"** account to **DB.html** and **"user"** account to **index.html** but i think i always failed in Retrieving the Child Value.

[image: This is my firebase database]

Comment: it seems as if firebase.auth().currentUser returns a promise and needs to be handled asynchronously, if it is a promise, use then or await

Comment: is it possible to use firebase.auth().currentUser twice in one JavaScript file?, if it's posible i use two firebase.auth().currentUser and the other one doesnt have promise in it. Thank you for your reply btw...

Comment: If you `console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser)` at the start of this function, what does it print?

Comment: you should use `on` event listener in order to read the data from firebase.database(); adaRef.on("value", (snapshot) => // your code here)

Comment: Afrandra, if you think my answer solutionises for you, please click the green tick next to the answer. See here for more details on how to answer someones question:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You're not retrieving the data from the server. Remember you need to call .once('value') to get your query and then iterate through the remaining code based onw hether their value is of admin or user. [Firebase Docs has more explination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)  I've amended your code and put it below

```
  function sontinue() {
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            var uid = user.uid; 

            var adaRef = firebase.database().ref("User/" + uid).orderByChild("Role");
            //you now need to retrieve the data

            return adaRef.once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
                return snapshot.forEach(snapshot=>{
                if (snapshot.child("Role").val()==="admin") {
                location.href = "DB.html";
                 } else {
                location.href = "index.html";
                }
                return console.log("added");
                })

            })


        }
```

If you just wanted to find out who was of the user type admin...i'd use this below...much more efficient.

```
   function sontinue() {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var uid = user.uid; 

        var adaRef = firebase.database().ref("User/" + uid).orderByChild("Role").equalTo("admin");
        //you now need to retrieve the data

        return adaRef.once('value').then((snapshot)=>{
            //you now have all the users that are just admins
            return snapshot.forEach(snapshot=>{
            location.href = "DB.html";
            return console.log("added");
            })

        })


    }
```

Comment: If the answer works for you please don't forget to upvote / click the green tick next to the answer to say it's correct:

stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.